# Why using NSLayoutConstraint.activate is more efficient than .isActive = true?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

My question is about the creation of constraints: why creating an array of constraints to be activated later with the `activate` method is more efficient than activating each one by one with `.isActive = true`?

Activating a direct constraint, we're basically changing an attribute, a variable that's already instantiated in the `UIView` we're tinkering with:

```swift
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
open var topAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor { get }
```

But the definition shows that using the Array is more efficient:

```swift
/* Convenience method that activates each constraint in the contained array, in the same manner as setting active=YES.
This is often more efficient than activating each constraint individually. */
@available(iOS 8.0, *)
open class func activate(_ constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint])
```

I don't see how to create an array of a variable that is already in scope and then pass it in a loop to activate it. How is this more efficient than enabling direct constraint?

Comment: Might want to watch https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/220/ - it has some great details.

Comment: Why is your code targeting iOS 9? (For the record, I *still* have apps targeting this that involve CoreImage.) I get trying to be efficient. But in terms of iOS (or even iPadOS) I'm not seeing the actual issue. The hardware is so much better than those days.... Can you give more details?

Comment: @dfd this code i get direrctly from the definition.

Comment: Understood. AutoLayout is an interesting animal - and poorly documented. At that point I'd go with the answer, which I'll upvote in a moment. Work with the engine... set `isActive = true` where possible and activate/deactivate the others as needed. Look at any warnings and, again, where possible, eliminate them. Most of all? If it works, it works. Don't sweat the small stuff - and by that I mean being "efficient" is small compared to the AutoLayout engine breaking the wrong constraint in your layout.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you have multiple constraints you need to activate, AutoLayout has no idea when you're going to be "done" activating them if you go one by one. This might lead it to  perform some intermediate calculations *between* constraints, whose results are wasted by adding another constraint immediately afterwards. By providing AutoLayout a list of constraints at once, it can both make sure it doesn't perform *any* intermediate calculations in between activations, and can get a better idea of the changes being made, leading to potentially more accurate and performant calculations.

---

If you poke around in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAutoLayout.framework` with a disassembler like Hopper, you might (currently) see:

- The implementation of `+[NSAutolayoutConstraint activateConstraints:]` is a passthrough to the private `+[NSAutolayoutConstraint _addOrRemoveConstraints:activate:]`
- `+[NSAutolayoutConstraint _addOrRemoveConstraints:activate:]`, for each constraint, tries to get a reference to the layout engine that the constraint belongs to (`-[NSLayoutConstraint _layoutEngine]`), and

  - If it belongs to an engine, activates or deactivates the constraint by calling through to the engine's `-[NSISEngine withAutomaticOptimizationsDisabled:]` method
  - If it doesn't yet belong to an engine, it will activate the constraint directly

`-[NSLayoutConstraint setActive:]` itself also does a non-trivial amount of work, potentially searching for its `_nearestAncestorLayoutItem` to `_findCommonAncestorOfItem:andItem:` in order to insert into the right place. By doing this work inside of a context that has optimizations disabled, autolayout can avoid doing that unnecessary work for each and every one of the constraints in the list.

---

The amount of work that AutoLayout has to do for each of your constraints likely dwarfs the cost of creating an array to store them temporarily, though you can likely profile this in a live app to see what it might be costing you.